# What are relevant skills for the Captain of the Guard/Hammerer positions?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My latest fort is finally at the point where I'm starting to set up prisons and a justice system, but it's hard to find suitable dorfs for the positions of law enforcement.

Which skills should be considered "relevant" or even just useful for the captain of the guard I'm going to appoint?

Answer (score 2):

When you don't have a prison, its kind of important to make sure that your sheriff or captain of the guard doesn't have ridiculous strength. When you don't have a prison, justice is handed out in the form of beatings and he may kill/severely wound dwarfs for trivial crimes.

Also, make sure you have helpers for the `Captain of the Guard` as if punishment isn't swift for criminals it will be handed out by the `Hammerer`, i.e. The Executioner.

In general, the only common quality that should be in your justice system are the weaker dwarves that are unskilled in combat. Thus, not killing your criminals. A good compromise is to equip them with `Feather Tree` shields and `Adamantite` crossbows so that they can still help out if you are invaded.

It doesn't seem as if though any other skills are relevant to picking law enforcement.

Comment: Clothed dwarves should shrug off an assault with training swords no matter what the attacker's skill. Naked dwarves will be annihilated by a Wooden Sword of Dullness in the hands of a skilled warrior.

Comment: @kotekzot I don't see your point?

Comment: The point is that it's handy to know?

Comment: @kotekzot Ha sorry, I just thought it was something to do with my answer being wrong or something.

Comment: I've got a prison, and I've kitted out every cell with its very own food and drink stockpile. I'm asking about what skills would make a Captain of the Guard more effective at his/her job.

Comment: @Shadur nothing really. Just try not to let them kill everyone

Comment: I believe the Hammerer now insists on having an actual hammer, rather than some other non-weapon. You can still give him an adamantine hammer (if you have access to adamantine) but short of that you may be forced to let him have an actual dangerous weapon; I don't think he'll be satisfied with a crossbow. Beware.